# What widget should I use for full width?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**I am using Wrap widget and I got following result.**

[image: I am using Wrap widget and got following result]

**But I want full width like the following image**

[image]

*What widget should I use? Please guide me a for a piece of code snippet*

Comment: use can use this plugin for you'r use case https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets , and use WrapSuper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [assorted_layout_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets) package. That is exactly what I want.

```
WrapSuper(
                  wrapType: WrapType.balanced,
                  wrapFit: WrapFit.larger,
                  spacing: 8.0,
                  lineSpacing: 8.0,
                  children:[]),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this layout you can either use staggeredGridView or if you wish to keep the wrap you have to define the width of each widget. You can probably use

```
SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.31, //0.33 will give 1/3 of the width.
  child: Container(), // your widget here
),
```

Comment: I think, SizedBox will take fix width for each. I want dynamic item as it can take but with full width.

Comment: Yes if you wish to have 3 items in one row then it will occupy 1/3 width and align itself.

Comment: You can also try wrapAlignment.spaceEvenly